# How to system out for Android(xperia Z)

Tags: android

I'm using Xperia Z as a debug device and Logcat to debug. But in Logcat when a exception is throw with out catch I cannot debug it like Java. Example in Java I can find information like this

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   MyServer.main(MyServer.java:260)

I think if I can use system out in java i can get the information in Android.

Please send to me advises

Thanks!

Comment: On Android, Logcat essentially IS System.out, although you should use the android.util.Log methods instead of calling System.out.print/println.

Comment: how can i print Exception without catch like my example in logcat ?? in logcat a lot of information that I don't view but it is shown, it make me confuse when i debug too

Comment: `Log.e(String, String, Throwable)` will print a message to logcat and will print a stack trace from the Throwable argument. Yiou can filter your logs in eclipse by tag, app package, log level, etc. I suggest you read this: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#logcat

Answer (score 0):

Just try this to debug Android errors:

```
import android.util.Log;
Log.d(String tag, String msg);
```

Where parameters (taken from the docs):

1. **tag** Used to identify the source of a log message. It usually identifies the class or activity where the log call occurs.
2. **msg** The message you would like logged.